# Remove price from select option in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2

I have Commented these lines:

> if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {
>                                   options[i].label = options[i].label + ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(
>                                       optionPriceDiff,
>                                       this.options.priceFormat,
>                                       true);
>                               }

But it's not effecting.

Comment: try this: https://stuntcoders.com/snippets/remove-magento-pricing-for-options-in-dropdown-on-both-simple-and-configurable-products/

Comment: please elaborate your issue in detail, also share your code you've tried or share a screenshot of the error you're facing